# Minimum value of $\frac{pr}{q^2}$ in quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $y^4-2y^2+4+3\cos(py^2+qy+r)=0$ has $2$ solutions and $p,q,r\in(2,5)$. Then minimum of $\displaystyle \frac{pr}{q^2}$ is.

solution I try

$$-3\cos(py^2+qy+r) =(y^2-1)^2+3\geq 3$$

$$\cos(py^2+qy+r)\leq -1\implies \cos(py^2+qy+r)=-1$$

$$py^2+qy+r=(4n+1)\pi\implies py^2+qy+r-(4n+1)\pi=0$$

for real and distinct roots

$$q^2-4p[r-(4n+1)\pi ]\geq 0$$

How do I find minimum of $\displaystyle \frac{p r}{q^2}$? Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as $(y^2 - 1)^2 + 3 (1 + \cos (py^2 + qy + r)) = 0$. Both terms on the LHS are manifestly non-negative, so the equation is solved only when both terms are zero. The only possible solutions are $y = \pm 1$, and both are obtained only when $p+q+r$ and $p-q+r$ are both odd multiples of $\pi$. As $2 < p-q+r < p+q+r < 15$, this is only possible if $p - q + r = \pi$ and $p + q + r = 3\pi$, which can be solved to give $q = \pi$ and $p + r = 2\pi$. The quantity to minimize is thus $$\frac{pr}{q^2} = \frac{p (2\pi - p)}{\pi^2}$$ which takes possible values $$\frac{10\pi - 25}{\pi^2} < \frac{pr}{q^2} \leq 1,$$ the maximum attained at $p = \pi$ and the infimum (not strictly a minimum, as the allowable interval for $p$ is open) obtained at the endpoint $p = 5$.

Comment: If your reasoning is right, then your conclusion should be that there is no minimum in the interval.

Comment: @Allawonder This is pedantry, but I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: I don't think it is. If this function were to model a physical process, your approach could cause a lot of problems for the analyst, who is assuming something unrealistic. Even mathematically speaking, the function doesn't attain the value since its domain is open (you might as well compute the maximal value of $1/x$).

Answer (score 1):

The condition for

$$
y^4-2y^2+4+3\sigma(y)=0
$$

with $-1 \le \sigma(y) \le 1$

to have real roots is that $\sigma(y) = -1$ or $p y^2+q y+ r = \pi$ but then $y = y_0 = \pm 1$ hence

$$
\min \frac{pr}{q^2}\\
\mbox{subjected to}\\
p y^2_0+q y_0 + r = \pi \\
(p,q,r)\in (2,5)^3
$$

and the minimum value is $\frac{1}{2(2-\pi)}$ for both $y_0 = \pm 1$

As example of solution

$$
p = 2\\
q = 2(\pi-2)\\
r = 2-\pi
$$

Comment: Your criterion $p y_0^2 + q y_0 + r = 0$ is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I will make the due  changes.

Comment: The root of the problem is that you need $\sigma(y) = -1$.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to include this.